# Проверка продан ли товар на амазоне

Tags: api, amazon

Здравствуйте. Имеется сайт на котором парсятся товары с амазона, и у каждого товара есть реферальная ссылка. Может кто-нибудь знает как через API определить продан ли товар по этой ссылке ?